# Adding `import` statement to `global.d.ts` destroys type and module declarations

Tags: typescript, swagger, openapi

In my Next.js web project, my `types/global.d.ts` starts like this:

```
declare module 'react-zeroconfig-components'

interface Product {
  ...
}
```

I’m using `openapi-typescript` to generate types from my Swagger OpenAPI definitions, but when I import my generated `swagger.ts` file:

```
import { definitions } from 'types/swagger'

declare module 'react-zeroconfig-components'

interface Product {
  ...
}
```

…none of the other types/interfaces in `global.d.ts` work any longer:

```
Type error: Cannot find name 'Product'.
```

and also the `declare module` stops working:

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-zeroconfig-components'
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `import` makes the file a module and no longer an ambient type declaration file. To fix this, use the import function syntax:

```
type SomethingCool = import("types/swagger").definitions;
```

This is because if you import something and hover over it:

```
import mod from "cool-module";
```

You will probably see that the editor (at least VSCode) displays `import("cool-module")` as the type.

So here we'll use this to mitigate the use of a static `import` keyword.

Comment: import statement should is async and this will not extract the needed types